# Problem with unescaping unicode strings

Tags: python, unicode

I have a problem with unescapting unicode string. I tried the following, but it doesn't work with unicode chars.

```
>>> s = ur"\'test\'"
>>> s.decode("string_escape")
"'test'"
>>> s = ur"\'test \u2014\'"
>>> s.decode("string_escape")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in position 7:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there a better way to remove the backslashes?

*Btw: I need this, because [xmlrpclib.ServerProxy](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html) escapes the responses.*

**Edit:** Here's an example for my xmlrpc request:

```
>>import xmlrpclib
>>server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/")
>>xml_data = server.tag.search({'api_key':'...','tag':'80s'})
>>print xml_data
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<lfm status=\"ok\">
<results for=\"80s\" xmlns:opensearch=\"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/\">
<opensearch:Query role=\"request\" searchTerms=\"80s\" startPage=\"1\" />
...
```

I think the escapes comes from the xmlrpc server.

Comment: Doesn't xmlrpclib handle both escaping and unescaping alone? And doesn't it use XML escapes?

Comment: I just see that the escapes could come from the xmlrpc server, because it sends a xml string in the xml response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's `"string_escape"` and `"unicode_escape"`, either can't decode the string that you have given. The first reads a bytestring escaped as a bytestring, and decodes it as a bytestring. The second reads an unicode string escaped and saved in a bytestring, so it can't read an input unicode objects, at least not ones that do have unicode characters in them.

I believe that the raw string you've given here is wrong, and you actually want `s.decode('unicode_escape')` for the real strings coming from your source.

If I'm incorrect, the best you can do is to manually escape any unescaped single quotes with `re`, put extra single quotes around it and use `ast.literal_eval`.

```
def substitute(match):
    if len(match.group(1)) % 2 == 1:
        return match.group()
    else:
        return ur"%s\%s" % (match.group(1), match.group(2))

ast.literal_eval("'%s'" % re.sub(ur"(\\+)(')", substitute, s))
```

A third option is that the string needs to be passed to `ast.literal_eval` without any additional work on your part. Which of the three depends on what you exactly have as a string.

Another suspicion I have is that it might be a JSON object. You should give an example of the string that you're getting, and where are you getting it from and how.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, the error you posted does not seem to occur using Python 2.6.4:

```
In [110]: s = ur"\'test\'"

In [111]: s.decode("string_escape")
Out[111]: "'test'"

In [112]: s = ur"\'test \u2014\'"

In [113]: s.decode("string_escape")
Out[113]: "'test \xe2\x80\x94'"

In [114]: print(s.decode("string_escape"))
'test —'
```